# 3D polyline editing

Tags: arcgis-10.1, 3d-analyst

I have a question similar to Poalo's question.
[Polyline ZM: automatic vertex height errors correction](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57777/polyline-zm-automatic-vertex-height-errors-correction).
It could be that I am using the wrong workflow.
I have a 3d polyline feature class in sde.
**EDIT:** I get updates (via a 2d shapefile) to that fc and move the polyline.
I start an edit, edit vertices and snap to the update shapefile polyline.
Now I want to "Update" the z elevations that I moved.
If I am not mistaken the only method to do that with an sde fc. Is to...

1. move features
2. interpolate to a new fc
3. truncate the sde table
4. load new fc with updated z.

Is this the "only" workflow available?
I see add z inormation, and feature to 3d by attribute. But that would assume I have a way to update the attribute with correct elevations. There are too many to do this manually.
Please let us know if there is a way to do this "in" the feature class.
**EDIT2:**
I would like to do this in a gui (not programmatic). I also do not use the vertex only option when interpolating.
The problem domain is that after editing sde I want to update the shapez values with a dem. I don't write code so if it can be done in a toolbox, calculator, or other interface I can accomplish without help with code.  I am fairly aquainted with sql and vbscript for field calculation but only to tinker/load.

Comment: Are you looking to do this programmatically? I am sure that there are other workflows -- if the only way to edit in SDE was to truncate and append, no one would use it. Could you describe your "I get updates to that fc and move the polyline" process in more detail? How does (or should) that affect the Z values?

Comment: I normally use toolbox to interpolate.

Comment: How should the Z values be affected by being moved? Is there a TIN or DEM you are interpolating against, and you want the polyline Z values to match it whenever they are moved?

Comment: correct I can see that I need to interpolate again but don't see how to do it without writing a new file.

Comment: Well in ArcObjects you could use [`ISurface.Z`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000001nz000000) to get the TIN/DEM's elevation at each vertex of the polyline. You have not clearly defined the problem domain yet though. Are you looking for a programmatic solution and if so with which APIs and languages are you comfortable?